# Seurat DimPlot - Highlight specific groups of cells in different colours

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rna-seq, seurat

I apologise for the question that might be very basic, but I cannot figure this out:

I have a Seurat object with 20 different groups of cells (all are defined in metadata and set as *active.ident*). 10 of them are "treated" and 10 are "untreated" (this info is also in metadata).

[R Seurat package](https://satijalab.org/seurat/)

I am trying to make a DimPlot that highlights 1 group at a time, but the colours for "treated" and "untreated" should be different.

my working code highlights both "treated" and "untreated" in the same colour:

```
DimPlot(integrated, label = T, group.by = "Treat", 
        cells.highlight = WhichCells(integrated, 
                                     idents = c("group1_untreated", "group1_treated")), 
        cols.highlight = c("darkblue", "darkred"), cols = "grey")
```

What is the right way to do it?

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the UMAP coordinates from the Seurat object and use `ggplot` to achieve this.

```
library(tidyverse)

umap_tx = integrated@reductions$umap@cell.embeddings %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% cbind(tx = so@meta.data$Treat)

ggplot(umap_tx, aes(x=UMAP_1, y=UMAP_2, color=tx)) + geom_point() + 
scale_color_manual(values=c("group1_untreated" = "darkblue", 
                            "group1_treated" = "darkred"))
```